# Generar ruta de migración MSOes → SOes

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-rechazado, meta, migración

No solíamos tener preguntas publicadas en Meta que correspondían al sitio principal, pero pasó al menos 3 veces esta semana ([1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1919/127), [2](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1959/127), [3](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1964/127)).

Creo que sería más práctico tener la ruta para migrar desde acá a SOes, sin la necesidad de generar un reporte personalizado a un moderador. Ya existe la ruta inversa (SOes → MSOes), y esperaría bastante menos conflicto y una decisión muchísimo más informada en los votos de Meta.

¿Podemos generarla?

Comment: Yo acabo de votar para cerrarla como no relacionado, pero estoy de acuerdo, debería ser a la inversa también.

Comment: Sí, será útil hacerlo. Actualmente en SOes no tenemos definidos motivos específicos de "no relacionado". Este puede bien ser uno. Sería interesante también hacer un poco de análisis de los [motivos de cierre](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days) que se han usado para ver si hace falta crear alguno más.

Comment: @fedorqui ...... pero sólo porque me lo pediste vos. [Motivos de cierre como “no relacionado” en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1961/127)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Just wanted to confirm that this is on the CM team's backlog. We'll get back to you once we have any updates or requests for clarification :)

Comment: He hablado con los moderadores del sitio y realizamos que el número de veces que se necesitaría una ruta de MSOes -> SOes no son suficientes para justificar añadirla. Sigamos usando el proceso normal por ahora.

Comment: Mmmm entonces no entiendo nada, ¿por qué se escaló si los mods no iban a quererlo? (cc @Pikoh pero sin saber quién lo ha gestionado, gracias por vuestro tiempo)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' lo escalé yo, pero escalarlo no significa automáticamente que se apruebe :) En este caso, se ha hablado entre los moderadores del sitio y los CM y se ha decidido por el momento que no es necesaria dado el bajo numero de ocasiones en los que sería necesaria. Esto no impide que si en el futuro este número aumenta no se pueda volver a solicitar y sea implantado.

Comment: @Pikoh entiendo. Lo que me extrañaron fueron dos cosas: 1) Que si los moderadores tampoco lo veían claro, con no escalarlo ya habríamos parado el tema (demasiadas alforjas para tan poco viaje). 2) Que si es una opción que existe y que tantos otros sitios ya tienen, no se implemente, máxime cuando no hay ninguna otra posible migración desde Meta. Por pocas ocasiones que se use (algunas al mes), creo que empodera a la comunidad y reduce la necesidad de tirar de moderadores. Dicho lo cual, gracias por gestionarlo y por las explicaciones. A ver si resuelven los otros [meta-tag:estado-en-revisión].

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' El punto 1 es culpa mia. Tal vez antes de haberlo escalado debería haber consultado con el resto de moderadores, algo que no hice. En cuanto al punto 2, se nos ha comentado que en SO no existe la ruta de SOMeta a SO..no lo he comprobado la verdad

Comment: @Pikoh sí, sí hay ruta SO -> SOMeta: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyN66.png. Y para nada debes disculparte, soy consciente de que esta iniciativa de Mariano (que comparto) la escalaste al poner yo un reporte pidiéndolo. Entiendo que el diálogo con los CM aporta elementos nuevos que ayudan a tener más perspectiva, de ahí que pida los detalles que sean compartibles para así también entenderlo mejor. Gracias, no tiene mayor relevancia el tema. Un saludo!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' si, hay de SO -> SOMeta (aqui tambien). Pero lo que se pide aqui es la ruta inversa SOMeta -> SO, que parece que no existe en SO tampoco

Comment: oh, disculpa @Pikoh tienes razón. Pues efectivamente, no la hay. Tampoco en [su] ni [ubuntu.se], que también miré.