# Nuevos motivos de cierre como "no relacionado" en Meta

Tags: característica-nueva, cierre-de-preguntas, meta, motivos-de-cierre

¿Nos conviene agregar motivos de cierre personalizados en Meta? ¿Cuáles?

Actualmente tenemos:

[image: Cierre > No relacionado || Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre Stack Overflow o el software que hace que la red Stack Exchange funcione, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda. || Otro (añade un comentario explicando cuál es el problema)]

Esto es:

> Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre Stack Overflow o el software que hace que la red Stack Exchange funcione, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda.

y

> Otro (añade un comentario explicando cuál es el problema)

Answer (score 5):

> Esta es una propuesta que tomó contenido de MSE, MSO y MSOpt, se discutió en conjunto y es la que acordamos que sería la mejor opción entre todos los que participaron.

Los cierres en Meta no son una problemática actual, pero la idea de esta propuesta es parametrizar los motivos de cierre de "otros" para fácilmente poder contar en el futuro con métricas consistentes.

Motivos:

## Cierre > No relacionado

- Esta pregunta **no parece que busque el aporte y la comunicación** en la comunidad. Si encuentras un problema en nuestro sitio, descríbelo detalladamente. Más información en [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).
- El problema descrito **ya no puede reproducirse**. Las modificaciones en el sistema, o en las circunstancias que lo afectan, lo han vuelto obsoleto. Si encuentras un problema similar, por favor [formula una nueva pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).
- **Claramente no relacionado** (esta pregunta no tiene nada que ver con Stack Overflow en español ni con el software que potencia la red Stack Exchange).
- Esta pregunta pertenece a otro sitio de la red Stack Exchange.

  - Pertenece a [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
- Otro (añade un comentario explicando cuál es el problema).

---

#### Comentarios relevantes sobre lo que nos llevó a definir esos motivos:

1. En el primer motivo, reemplacé intencionalmente "discusión" por "comunicación", ya que me parece una mejor forma de describirlo y permite un alcance más amplio, evitando conceptos [erróneos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1926/127) sobre qué es discusión en Meta.
2. "Más que evidentemente no relacionado", además de que lo tomé de MSE ("blatantly off-topic"), me pareció una buena idea reforzar la idea de que hay más libertad en Meta respecto a qué se puede publicar. La idea es evitar que se use para casos limítrofes (o no tanto) con la excusa de que "*como  'no relacionado' está en los motivos de cierre, entonces hay que cerrarla*".

   - [@fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui) [comentó](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1961/nuevos-motivos-de-cierre-como-no-relacionado-en-meta#comment5920_1962) que preferiría sin "*Más que evidentemente*", que no la ve necesaria. ¿Qué opinan?
   - **EDITADO:** Modificado a "Claramente no relacionado"
     <sup>* [aceptamos barco](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattergories#Por_qu.C3.A9_es_conocido_el_juego) después de varios comentarios.</sup>
3. Se propuso [Generar ruta de migración MSOes → SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1960/127).

Comment: Las herramientas de moderación funcionan bien. ¿Que preguntas hay que merezcan esos motivos de cierre? Si respondes: son solo unos pocos casos, bastaría escribirlos en la opción _"Otros"_ las pocas veces que se requieran. Lo digo en serio, sin ironía.

Comment: @toledano los motivos de cierre son parte de las herramientas de moderación. En ningún momento las estoy cuestionando, ni diciendo que funciona mal (no entiendo el por qué de esa primera oración)... Ambos sabemos que son realmente muy pocas las preguntas que actualmente se cierran en meta, y no creo que aporte mucho evaluar una por una para ver en qué motivo de estos caería. Esta no es una propuesta que cambie ninguna funcionalidad actual. (cont.)

Comment: [cont.] La idea es parametrizar el cierre de "otros" para no tener que hacer la pregunta que estás haciendo, y poder saber fácilmente en el futuro cuántas se cerraron por cada uno de estos motivos. No intento cubrir una problemática actual, sino los principales motivos que puedan darse. Esto no implica un cambio, es simplemente agregar en la configuración... Emprolijarlo de la mejor manera que se nos pueda ocurrir.

Comment: A mí tampoco me convence demasiado la de "más que evidentemente...". No la veo necesaria a día de hoy, vaya. En cuanto al uso de "comunicación", tal vez podamos optar por "debate", no tan seria como "discusión" pero que sí tiene la connotación de confontar ideas.

Comment: @fedorqui buscaba que "comunicación" también incluya anuncios, solicitudes de usuarios a empleados de SE y viceversa (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Mmmm entiendo pero tal vez podría buscarse algo más explícito que ya lo explique: "no busca discusión ni es una comunicación de o hacia SE" ¿?

Comment: Había entendido mal a Mariano. Estoy de acuerdo con todos los puntos que expone en esta respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui Me parece bien... Ya quemé las naves por hoy y no se me ocurre cómo sería sin que se haga demasiado largo. (si se te ocurre cómo, editalo directamente).

Comment: El problema que le veo a _Más que evidentemente no relacionado_ es que no se me ocurren casos en que se pueda usar que no sean ya gestionables con el motivo _no parece que busque el aporte y la comunicación_. Tal vez con algún ejemplo me haré más a la idea :)

Comment: @fedorqui pensaba en un caso del estilo "¿Qué opinan del 3 a 1 de ayer de River en la Bombonera?"... Aunque te imaginarás otros casos de esa índole.

Comment: @Mar entiendo... sin embargo buceando en la lista de [preguntas cerradas hasta la fecha](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3aq%20closed%3ayes) no encuentro casos en los que hubiera sido necesario este motivo. Ojo, que no se haya usado no quiere decir que no vaya a necesitar en el futuro, pero considero más útil ceñirnos a la necesidad actual comprobada.

Comment: @fedorqui no, de lo que estuve viendo o recuerdo, no hubo... La idea (comentado antes) era https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1961/nuevos-motivos-de-cierre-como-no-relacionado-en-meta/1962#comment5916_1962 ... En MSE tampoco encontré casos en los que se haya aplicado, pero está este motivo. Aunque también me parecía bueno una doble función: acotar a que si se cierra como "no relacionado", realmente no tiene nada que ver con SE.

Comment: Ya... Yo me centraría sin embargo en solventar el problema que tengamos (esto es, añadir motivos contrastados). Y si en el futuro se hace necesario algún otro, se añade. Al fin y al cabo añadirlos es fácil y hay hueco para tres, si no recuerdo mal.

Comment: @fedorqui hay 5 en MSE o en SOpt (usan "abertamente fora do assunto")

Answer (score 2):

El día de hoy, luego de ver el comentario de una pregunta que fue cerrada, he entrado a ver qué hay de nuevo en el diálogo de motivos de cierre *no relacionado* en el sitio en Inglés y me ha parecido que nos hace falta mejorar un poco en ese aspecto.

He visto que hay varias publicaciones en meta al respecto, así he seleccionado esta para publicar una respuesta, aunque no estaba muy seguro de si lo mejor es publicar una nueva pregunta.

El diálogo del sitio en inglés por ahora luce así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en español, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veo de particular utilidad mejorar la redacción, por lo que, inspirado en el diálogo en inglés, quiero sugerir que se cambie la redacción de los primeros dos motivos del diálogo en español por algo como:

- La pregunta fue causada por un problema que **ya no puede reproducirse** o un **error tipográfico simple**. Mientras que algunas preguntas similares serían aceptadas en el sitio, esta se resuelve de manera que poco puede ayudar a futuros lectores y pudo ser evitado al realizar un [mcve] antes de publicar la pregunta.
- Preguntas que buscan ayuda para depurar ("**por qué este código no funciona**") deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un *problema específico o mensaje de error exacto* y el menor código necesario para reproducir el problema **en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin un **enunciado claro del problema** no son de utilidad para otros lectores. Para más información vea [mcve]

Comment: Ambas existen, pero creo que la redacción debe mejorar un poco para hacerlas más claras, tanto a quién está cerrando una pregunta, como a quién se la cerraron.

Comment: Pues me parece bien. Cuanta más información útil, mejor, máxime cuando el objetivo es que el OP la utilice para intentar volver la pregunta en algo útil para la comunidad.